Getting all pids in a systemd unit
I'm using the Linux Citrix client and the latest versions has a tendency to leave processes behind. I came up with a little script to kill them using old-school unix commands and it works very well.
The script is a bit more complex than this, it uses ps + grep to look for processes before/after (including truncating with a + user names longer than 8 characters!) and tries multiple kill attempts with TERM then KILL signals, however the kill itself is dead simple:
pkill -$signal -f "-u$USER" '(ICA|Citrix)'

Now I though the way systemd manages processes, it would actually make much more sense to leverage it for killing these processes, and this would have a better chance of surviving changes in the citrix client. This is mostly academic for now, however I think it's the right way to think about system process management down the line so I would love to make it work.
I can already list all process in the group with the following command:
$ systemd-cgls --user-unit "$(systemctl --user show --property Id --value 'app-gnome-Citrix*')"
Unit app-gnome-Citrix_subscribed_[REDACTED]-3155246.scope (/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-gnome-Citrix_subscribed_[REDACTED]-3155246.scope):
├─3155248 /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/UtilDaemon
├─3155273 /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/AuthManagerDaemon
├─3155274 /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/ServiceRecord
[...]

However I cannot seem to find a way to get machine-parsable output out of systemd-cgls.
Is there a command I am missing to get what I want?
This is systemd 252.

I actually figured it out - one thing that puzzled me was that I could not find a tasks file or similar in the cgroup's directory. I apparently missed the part where the tasks file moved to cgroup.procs and cgroup.threads in Cgroups v2 (I looked for something similar but skipped over the cgroup. namespace prefix).
I can get the pid list with this command for example:
$ cat "/sys/fs/cgroup/$(systemctl --user show --property ControlGroup --value 'app-gnome-Citrix*')/cgroup.procs"
3155248
3155273
3155274
[...]

And even better, pgrep and pkill support a --cgroup filter too!
$ pgrep --cgroup "$(systemctl --user show --property ControlGroup --value 'app-gnome-Citrix*')"
3155248
3155273
3155274
[...]

The full script now:
#!/bin/bash
#
# Kill lingering Citrix processes
#
set -eu
trap 'echo "An error occurred at line $LINENO" >&2' ERR

res=$(systemctl --user show --property ControlGroup,Id --value 'app-gnome-Citrix*')
[ -n "$res" ] || exit 0

# groupid=([0]=<ControlGroup> [1]=<Id>)
mapfile -t groupid <<<"$res"
systemd-cgls --user-unit "${groupid[1]}"

sig=TERM
tries=0
while pkill -$sig "-u$USER" --cgroup "${groupid[0]}"; do
    ((++tries))
    # Abort after 5 attempts
    ((tries < 5)) || break
    # KILL on the 3rd attempt
    ((tries < 2)) || sig=KILL
    sleep 1
done

unit=$(systemctl --user show --property Id --value 'app-gnome-Citrix*')
[ -n "$unit" ] || exit 0
systemd-cgls --user-unit "$unit"

cat <<-EOF

    WARNING: Could not kill all processes after 5 tries!!!

    EOF
exit 1

